# How to change permanently an external file.txt?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I would like to change my file.txt on click.
For example, I wrote this:

**Html:**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="file.txt"></script>
```

**jQuery:**

```
 var counter = config.rans;
 var counter1 = config.bans;

$('.redanswer').one('click', function(){
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('PUT','file.txt', true);
    xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type','text/javascript; charset=utf-8');
    xhr.send( 'var config={"rans":' + ++counter + ',"bans":' + counter1 + '};' );
    $( '.rtotal' ).text( counter );
    $( '.btotal' ).text( counter1 );
});

$('.blueanswer').one('click', function(){
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('PUT','file.txt', true);
    xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type','text/javascript; charset=utf-8');
    xhr.send( 'var config={"rans":' + counter + ',"bans":' + ++counter1 + '};' );
    $( '.btotal' ).text( counter1 );
    $( '.rtotal' ).text( counter );
});
```

**file.txt:**

```
var config={"rans":10,"bans":20};
```

With this code when I click, for example, `redanswer` it is shown the number 11 because it's `rans`(10) + 1. But if I reload the page and I click again on the `redanswer` it is already shown the number 11 because the file.txt it isn't been edited. I would like to add a piece of code that, on click on the `redanswer`, can edit the file.txt like `var config={"rans":11,"bans":20}; //10+1`.

I hope you understand. Thank you very much.

Comment: PHP's documentation says "It is obviously not a good idea for Apache or PHP to automatically let everybody overwrite any files in your web tree. So, to handle such a request you have to first tell your web server that you want a certain PHP script to handle the request." See [PUT method support](http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.put-method.php).

Comment: Also, according to an article on [apacheweek.com](http://www.apacheweek.com/features/put), "...Apache handles PUT exactly like it handles the POST method. That is, it supports it, but in order for it to do anything useful you need to supply a suitable CGI program."

Answer (score 0):

Sadly this is not possible. 
**JavaScript does not have read/write capabilities**.

I suggest creating a simple POST or GET PHP api to be able to write files.